# cloudfoundry package dependencies in python buildpack

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to package a couple of dependencies which I need for running my python app. I have it already on my `requirements.txt` of my application. But dependencies like, `Cassandra-driver` is taking too much time to install every time I redeploy my app.

How can I package my python modules in the buildpack so that It won't install it every time I redeploy my app?

Comment: It might be hard to package in the build pack, cause you'd need to fork the build pack (not a good idea).  Maybe you could vendor it with your app?  Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Daniel

It worked! Here is what I need, maybe it will help someone.

```
$ cd yourproject
$ mkdir vendor
$ pip install -d vendor -r requirements.txt
$ cf push
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and found in the documentation: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html#vendoring

Regards.